# GMSMapView myLocation dot is overlapped with custom pins

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using GoogleMaps SDK in my iOS project.
[myLocationEnabled](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view#a04faba924be73a0ea5bb9ae300da1c9a) property is set to YES.
I expect the user location pin hovering over all other pins like it does on Android. But for some reason it is overlapped with other map pins. 
[image]
Googling didn't give me anybody with similar problem. What could I do wrong? I'm using standard GMSMapView workflow when adding pins on the map.

```
GMSMarker * marker = [[GMSMarker alloc]init];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
//cluster - is just an object of business logic
coordinate.latitude = [cluster.latitude floatValue];
coordinate.longitude =[cluster.longitude floatValue];
[marker setIcon:markerIcon];
[marker setPosition:coordinate];
[marker setUserData:cluster];
[marker setMap:mapView_];
```

Comment: I have this problem with the latest SDK (1.8), too—appears to be a bug, uncertain of the age.

Comment: I am having the same problem, here in 2019 using version 3.0.2 of the Google Maps SDK. Have you ever solved the problem?

Comment: unfortunately nope